# Getting Rank by id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the rank of a student in a table by the student's id.
The code below will help to explain my problem.
The name of the table is Student,it has id and marks as its columns.

```
SELECT id, marks, 
  @curRank := IF(@prevVal=marks,@curRank,@studentNumber) AS rank,     
  @studentNumber := @studentNumber + 1 as studentNumber,
  @prevVal:=marks 
FROM Student,(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevVal:=null, @studentNumber:=1 ) r 
ORDER BY marks  DESC where id='001';
```

The code above is able to select all list of student's id and their rank without the `where id='001'` but i want to select each student rank by its id. 
I have tried the above codes to fix my problem but to no avail,please can some one help.This is how my table looks like when i execute the code above without `where id='001'`

```
  id     marks      rank
  002      92         1
  003      92         1
  001      80         3
```

I want to select marks and rank of where id = 001 like the output below

```
id        marks     rank
001         80         3
```

Comment: Could you show a few rows from the `Student` table, plus expected output?

Comment: Please i have update my question,hope that will help.Thanks

Comment: This will only be possible with temporary tables as far as I can see. You first have to compute the rank column into the temp table and then select the single student. Narrowing the result with a where will omit the rank otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the sorting and the rank calculation inside a subquery, then do the ID selection outside the subquery - like so:

```
select id, marks, rank from
(SELECT id, marks, 
   @curRank := IF(@prevVal=marks,@curRank,@studentNumber) AS rank,     
   @studentNumber := @studentNumber + 1 as studentNumber,
   @prevVal:=marks 
 FROM student,(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevVal:=null, @studentNumber:=1 ) r 
 ORDER BY marks  DESC ) sq
where id='001'
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0540f/3).

Comment: Thanks it works,i have understood where I am was going wrong.